# /etc/profile.d script interfering with a service starting, and considerably delaying ssh availability after reboot

Tags: bash-scripting, puppet, profile

I have created a script in `/etc/profile.d` (centos6), not related to puppet in any way, instead it just copy's some files to a users dir.  Somehow, on a puppet enterprise master server, this script is interfering with the service `pe-postgresql`, and causing the server to delay on boot, and will not let that service run.

This profile script has a feature that prompts a user on login and asks them if they want to install (y,n), if one of its files aren't found.  I suspect this is happening in the background to something when a puppet service is starting somewhere, causing that service to fail.

```
#/etc/profile.d/custom.sh
if [ ! f ~/.custom ]; then
    logPrompted;
    while true; do
        read -p "Do you want to install?)" yn
        case $yn in
         [Yy]* )
           installCustom;
           break;;
         [Nn]* )
           logOptedOut;
           break;;
         * ) echo "Please enter y or n!";;
        esac
    done
fi
```

As soon as move the file out of `/etc/profile.d`, the problems stop. E.g. `sudo service pe-postgresql start` fails every time when that script is in place.

When I look at puppet users `cat /etc/passwd | grep pe-` I  can verify that all of them are `nologin`.

There is either something im missing here, or another puppet service user that I'm missing. which is possibly interactive.

I added logging on each run to see when its ran(`logPrompted`), before the question, by reporting `$(whoami)`, hoping to uncover the hidden user, and on the log i do indeed see `pe-postgres` being logged each time "I" try to restart the service, but this is not consistent.

looking at /etc/passwd this user is `pe-postgres:x:492:493:Puppet Enterprise PostgreSQL Server:/opt/puppet/var/lib/pgsql:/sbin/nologin`

Im trying to figure out how i can avoid this user, or any `nologin` user to interact with this profile script.

Is there something I might need to add to the beginning of a profile.d script to safeguard it from these kinds of things?

Comment: Have you looked at the pe-postgresql service itself? (i.e. the one in /etc/init.d)

Comment: Excellent idea.  I do see this `$SU -l pe-postgres -s /bin/bash -c "$PGENGINE/postmaster -p '$PGPORT' -D '$PGDATA' ${PGOPTS} &" >> "$PGSTARTUPLOG" 2>&1 < /dev/null`.  Im guessing that why its triggering the script because its specifying /bin/bash.  
This was super cryptic, so i would rather safeguard my script to not prompt intended users.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prompts only make sense when the shell is interactive. (You wouldn't want them to interfere with e.g. SFTP connections...) To check for interactivity, you have two options:

- Test whether `$-` contains the letter `i`.

  ```
  case $- in
    *i*) <do your prompts>;;
    *) return;;
  esac
  ```

  Or:

  ```
  if ! case $- in *i*) false; esac; then
      <do your prompting>
  fi
  ```
- Use `[ -t 0 ]` to test whether *stdin* (file descriptor #0) is a terminal:

  ```
  if [ ! -t 0 ]; then
      return
  fi
  ```

  Or:

  ```
  if test -t 0; then
      <do prompts here>
  fi
  ```

(Since your script is "sourced" by a parent script, calling `return` outside functions is allowed and will return to the parent script. That allows you to avoid an extra level of indentation.)

The 2nd method (checking stdin) doesn't *actually* test interactivity – for example, `sh -l -c "some command"` would still pass the test when being run through a terminal. But it still works in many cases, because services and SFTP connections do not have a terminal allocated.